# Sharepoint UploadFile 'Specified argument was out of range of valid values'

Tags: development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I'm trying to duplicate a file from one library to another within a Remote Event Receiver.

When reaching the `UploadFile`-function, I get the following error:

`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: bytesToCopy`

Information about the function can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filefolderextensions.uploadfile). It has the following signature:

```
public static Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File UploadFile (this Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder, string fileName, System.IO.Stream stream, bool overwriteIfExists);
```

My code is:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    ClientResult<Stream> data = curItem.File.OpenBinaryStream();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (data != null && data.Value != null)
    {

         data.Value.CopyTo(stream);
         UploadedFile = destinationList.RootFolder.UploadFile(curItem.File.Name.ToString(), stream, true);
    }
}
```

As a note: `curItem`, `destinationList` and `curItem.File` are all loaded in the context.

How to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510815/sharepoint-uploadfile-specified-argument-was-out-of-range-of-valid-values) answered the question:

Courtesy of [Oerkelens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784290/oerkelens):

A quick google search lead me to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/deac7cb7-c677-47b0-acdc-c56b32dfaac8/uploading-bigger-files-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Someone had a similar problem (although he figured it had to do with file size) and solved it by resetting the stream before sending it to SharePoint:

```
using (var stream = content)
{
    ...
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <-- The missing statement
    ...
}
```

Hope that works for you as well :)